# creating a list of tuples from a list in Python

Tags: python

I have my first question here. I'm writing a code in Python. I have following list

```
X = [0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3]
```

I would like to create a new list made by tuples of two or a different number of elements of the first list as follows.

```
newList = [(0.2,0.3),(0.2,0.3),(0.2,0.3),(0.2,0.3),(0.2,0.3)]
```

I'm looking for a function of the lists or tuples. or maybe something easy, without the use of a big "For"

Comment: Doing it without a **big "for"** loop is a big challenge

Comment: fyi, the easiest solution without `map`, `lambda`, or even `tuple` is to just use `[(X[i], X[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(X), 2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` and `lambda`:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> list(map(lambda i: tuple(X[i: i+n]), range(0, len(X), n)))
>>> [(0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.3)]
```

Comment: this is Python 2.x code. For Python 3 you have to cast your `map` to `list`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I have edited the answer thanks for pointing out :)